# How do I create a list in Excel using item to item comparison?

Tags: microsoft-excel

I would like to make a list of items in Excel that will allow me to compare items in the list to one another and have the end result ranked in that order.

I choose item #1 over #2, #1 or #3, #1 or #4, #1 or #5 .....till the end of list.
Then #2 or #3, #2 or #4, #2 or #5 ........till the end of list.
Then #3 or #4, #3 or #5 ......till the end of list.
then #4 or #5, #4 or #5.......till the end of list.

This all resulting in a ranked list from most chosen to least....

Can it be done?

Comment: Welcome to SuperUser! It's not entirely clear to me what data you already have and what data you want.  Does the "I choose item #1..." block of text describe what you already have?

Comment: Can you edit your post with a simple example of the starting lists, and the final list?  I'm having trouble understanding from the paragraph.

Answer (score 0):

[That](http://www.articlejobber.com/tutorial/match_function_excel_20060219_1.html)  might do the trick.
Good luck.